# Second order ODE, separation of variables ??

Tags: differential

I have an ODE of the form:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}$

I understand how to separate variables and integrate if its first order, but it looks trickier if its second order, is there a general way to solve it ?

Comment: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy'}{dx}$, so if you have a function of $y'$ instead of $y$ on the $RHS$, you can solve using separation of variables

Comment: Yeah I know that, doesn't solve the problem and not the question I asked, but thank you anyway

Comment: Are you asking about how to solve $2^{nd}$ order $ODE$s using separation of variables or otherwise?

Comment: I'm asking how to solve a second order ODE of that form, where we can separate the variables into two independent functions,